# Bootstrap 5 text in image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm very newbie to bootstrap 5 and I have a question, how to position the text inside the image as in the provided first screenshot:

[image]

I tried using card-img and it didn't work.

I also tried to do it through cols, but it didn't work either. Didn't find anything similar in 2 hours of searching

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-2">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="100%" class="card-img rounded" src="./Assets/Blog/image 32.png" alt=" ">
        <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <h4 class="card-title">dasdsa </h4>
          <p class="card-text">123 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-2 ">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="100%" class="card-img rounded" src="./Assets/Blog/image 33.png" alt=" ">
        <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <p class="card-text">123 </p>
          <div class="link d-flex">
            <a href="#" class="card-link text-warning">Read More</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link text-warning">Book a Trip</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-2">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="100%" class="card-img rounded" src="./Assets/Blog/image 34.png" alt=" ">
        <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <p class="card-text">123 </p>
          <div class="link d-flex">
            <a href="#" class="card-link text-warning">Read More</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link text-warning">Book a Trip</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center gx-2">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img width="100%" class="card-img rounded" src="./Assets/Blog/image 35.png" alt=" ">
        <div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
          <p class="card-text">It is the seventh most populous city in Italy, at the heart of a metropolitan area of about one million people. </p>
          <div class="link d-flex">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `position-relative`-class for the card and then `position-absolute` on the div containing the text. You just need to add custom CSS with a direction like `inset: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` and a set an image to the background. Then, just add the text that you need.

Note: The usage of flexbox, was merely for styling purposes, alongside the background of the `p` tag.

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486312338219-ce68d2c6f44d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1472&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-img>p {
  background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <p>i am over the image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: first this is a botostrap question and should eb solved as this. Second this is a evry poor approach even for custom CSS. Using the image as background-image has a few issues for screen readers. It also requires to pre-set the height and width of the div fixed. asbolute positioning would be a way betetr approach and would work with the already existign markup.

Comment: Doesn't matter how you go for it, in both ways, you'll need to use CSS to make the text go over the image. Bootstrap has CSS as well, and I believe it could be great for him to learn how it is done.

Comment: `bootstrap has CSS aswell` - Bootstrap is a CSS Framework. The whole reason to use it is not to require to use a custom CSS but the framework classes.

Comment: At the end of the day. what I sent is an example of what he wanted, so I don't think it is that bad.. If you want, you can send an example using `position` instead of `background-img`, because if he decides to use `Google Dev Tools`, he will find out that the text doesn't go over the image magically.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to just use `justify-content-end` instead of `justify-content-center` in `card-img-overlay` element and also add `text-center` in your code.

```
<div class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-end text-center">
  .........
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use https://getuikit.com/docs/overlay

it's easy to use

add your image path and ulkit cdn into html code

```html
<div class="uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
    <div>

        <div class="uk-inline">
            <img src="images/photo.jpg" width="1800" height="1200" alt="">
            <div class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-primary uk-position-bottom">
                <p>Default Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>

        <div class="uk-inline">
            <img src="images/photo.jpg" width="1800" height="1200" alt="">
            <div class="uk-overlay-primary uk-position-cover"></div>
            <div class="uk-overlay uk-position-bottom uk-light">
                <p>Default Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```